# When creating products with POST, images Roles are not enabled (base/small/thumb/swatch), even after a following PUT

Tags: api, product-images, rest-api, media, media-images

When I add a product via the Magento 2 API and then add an image, the image is added and shows up under the "Images and Videos" tab, associated with the correct product.  However, none of the Image Roles (Base/Small/Thumbnail/Swatch) are selected, so the image does not show up on the site or the search results in the Magento admin.

I am sending a POST request to:

```
CURLOPT_URL => $URL . "/rest/default/V1/products/".$sku."/media"

$image_post_data = [
                "entry"=> [
                    "media_type"=>"image",
                    "label"=> "Image".$sku,
                    "position"=> 0,
                    "disabled"=> "false",
                    "types"=> [
                        "image","small_image","thumbnail","swatch_image"
                    ],
                    "content"=> [
                        "base64EncodedData"=> $image64,
                        "type"=> "image/jpeg",
                        "name"=> $sku."jpg"
                    ]
                ]
            ];
```

Thinking that it might be an issue with the POST command, I then try a PUT afterwards:

```
$requestUrl = 'http://MYSTORE.com/index.php/rest/V1/products/'.$sku.'/media/'.$imageid;

$put_data = [
    "entry"=> [
        "id"=> $imageid,
        "media_type"=>"image",
        "label"=>$sku,
        "position"=> 1,
        "types"=> ["image", "small_image", "thumbnail", "swatch_image"]                                
    ]
];
```

This also does not enable the image roles/types.  I'm not getting an error back and everything looks fine.  I can update the position and label using the PUT code successfully.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: did you try to send the images directly by the Save product endpoint? this worked for me

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the Save product endpoint in the list of REST API endpoints; do you have any further info on this?  Thank you!

Comment: it is under "catalogProductRepositoryV1 ", 
post /V1/products